# Como usar o OnUpdate=Cascade no Doctrine 2

Tags: doctrine-2

Pessoal tenho uma relação de muito para um em uma tabela e preciso colocar o OnUpdate em Cascade como eu faço pois se tento assim da erro:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="JN\Entity\Planos\Plano")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="plano_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL", onUpdate="CASCADE")
 **/
private $plano;
```

Obrigado

Comment: João, você pode me dizer por que quer esse tipo de comportamento? Valeu.

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti pelo seguinte eu sempre uso o onUpdate=Cascade, para manter a integridade das chaves quando se faz uma alteração em uma tabela que por conseguencia tem outras vinculadas a ela. No Doctrine foi o primeiro ORM que eu vi que deixou o onDelete e sumiu com o onUpdate. Sempre trabalhei assim e não conheço outra forma de manter a integridade dos dados quando ha relacionamentos que não este.

Comment: Se você precisa de um onUpdate para manter a integridade referencial, significa que algo no seu banco está modelado errado. Você poderia postar uma imagem do seu modelo de dados na pergunta?

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti pense em uma tabela de cliente e uma tabela de bairros por exemplo. Tabela de clientes eu tenho as seguites colunas: ID, Nome,id_bairro. e Na tabela bairros eu tenho as colunas ID, NomeBairro.Tenho um relacionamento e de 1 bairro para varios clientes. Suponhamos que o bairro centro seja ID 1 hoje e daqui a um mês por algum motivo ele mude para 4. Se tiver o OnUpdate sera trocado tudo automaticamente caso contrario somente manualmente. OU tem outro jeito?

Comment: Você quer alterar o id do bairro e com isso quer que as chaves estrangeiras da tabela `bairros` na tabela `clientes`, é isso?

Comment: Isto seria um dos exemplos mais simples. Mas seria este o pensamento.

Comment: Não é correto você alterar o id de uma linha em uma tabela, uma vez que, quando esse id é atribuido a uma linha, ele não pode ser alterado. O certo é, caso você queira alterar o bairro de uma pessoa, buscá-lo com o método `findOneBy` do `EntityRepository` e atribuí-lo ao usuário com `$user->setBairro($bairro)`.

Comment: Ok. compreendi. Vou mudar então. Muito obrigado pela explicação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

infelizmente não existe suporte ao `OnUpdate`, outra coisa que vale salientar é que o `OnDelete` apenas funciona no `InnoDB` caso esteja utilizando `MyISAM` não irá funcionar tratando-se de MySQL.

O que você pode fazer é utilizar o `cascade` em memória, embora exista uma ressalva de desempenho nessa técnica.

As opções de cascade estão todas documentadas aqui: 
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations

Comment: kabstergo eu tinha visto isto na documentação, mas ainda me restava uma pontinha de esperança. Pois sempre utilizo on On Delete e o On Update para controlar as movimentações derivadas das tabelas. Fica aqui a minha decepção com este ponto do Doctrine. Como é a forma correta de se trabalhar com estas situações quando se tem? Obrigado

Comment: @JoaoNivaldo aqui encontra-se a solicitação e discussão sobre o recurso http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-1628 aparentemente os desenvolvedores julgaram que não existe uma aplicação prática na qual seria atualizado o valor de um identificador(primary keys) a alegação é que isso não seria encargo da biblioteca ORM. Então a forma "correta" (segundo eles) seria realizar a operação fora da aplicação, atráves da base de dados já que a mesma suporta a atualização em cascata desses identificadores.

Comment: eu concordo plenamente que isto é uma tarefa do Banco de dados e não do ORM. Mas se não existe a opcao onUpdate no anotation quando eu faço uma atualização nas classes e rodo o orm:schema-tool:update ele altomaticamente coloca o onUpdate em restrict ai eu vou no MySql e altero isto para Cascata ai eu mudo as classes e esqueço da mudança ai o resultado é problema na certa. Tem como fazer o Doctrine não alterar o onUpdate que esta no MYSQL quando eu rodar o comando de atualzar as tabelas?

Comment: @JoaoNivaldo hmm entendi o seu problema, vou pesquisar a respeito se eu achar algo eu atualizado a resposta.

Comment: muito obrigado.